# Generating Multiple Variables and use them to declare order of Array

Tags: java, arrays

So, Ive been messing around with Java, and I was wanting to do one thing regarding Array's and Number. So, I have been trying to create a program that tells me what classes go first for my homework. Its a simple idea, but I'm having problems with creation. The things that I am having trouble with are the following. A, I can't seem to find or create code that generates more than one number, if someone can point me in the right direction, that would be great. Also, I can't seem to use that generated number to grab a value from the array, even though I tried to do so. My code is the following::

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        createArray();
    }

    public static void createArray() {
        String[] array = new String[7];
        array[1] = "Class1";
        array[2] = "Class2";
        array[3] = "Class3";
        array[4] = "Class4";
        array[5] = "Class5";
        array[6] = "Class6";
        array[7] = "Class7";
    }
}
```

Also, let it be known that I DONT want direct answers, I want ideas and responses that will point me in the right direction so I can achieve it myself. Thank you, if you have any questions, please ask and I will do my best to clarify.

Comment: What do you mean by "code that generates more than one number"? Is that a random number generator? Please post what you have tried.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve. Do you want a specific way to order your Array of Strings? Where and for what do you want to use Numbers?

Comment: That function returns void and there are no arguments in the function. I don't see how you will retrieve the created array that way.

Comment: Oh, and arrays are indexed from zero, not one.

Answer (score 1):

If what you trying to achieve is an Array with generated numbers, you should see these links:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Those techniques are used to generate random numbers. While Math.random() generates numbers from 0.0 to 1, with Random class you have more flexibility. For instance, you can generate integers from 0 to 1000.

Nevertheless, you need a loop structure (do/while/for) to create your array.

Is this helpfull for your problem? If not, could you be more specific on what you're trying to achieve?